# Minimization problem of $\Phi$ is that the zero vector in $R^d$ belongs to the subdifferential of $\Phi$.

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the Lasso minimization problem, which is
$$
\min_{\theta\in R^d} \frac{1}{n}\|Y-X\theta\|_2^2   \, s.t. \|\theta\|_1\le t
$$
for some $t>0$.

Define $\Phi(\theta)=\frac{1}{n}\|Y-X\theta\|_2^2+2r\|\theta\|_1$. Why a necessary and sufficient condition for a vector $\theta$ to minimize $\Phi$ is that the zero vector in $R^d$ belongs to the subdifferential of $\Phi$ at point $\theta$, that is
$$
\frac{1}{n}[X^T(Y-X\theta)]_j=sign(\theta_j)r
$$
if $\theta_j\neq 0$.

Is this a classic conclusion? What reference books are there?

Comment: What do you know about optimality conditions for minimization problems? The conclusion you are asking about is immediate by writing those down.

Comment: @VHarisop Sorry, I do not know. Can you explain more details? Thanks!

Comment: It is the equivalent of the slope being zero for a differentiable convex function. It is a basic result and, I imagine, would be in most books that deal with convex optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $\Phi(\theta)$ is a convex function. The first-order optimality condition reads:

$$
\theta \in \arg\min \Phi \Leftrightarrow 0 \in \partial \Phi(\theta),
$$

where $\partial \Phi(\theta)$ is the subdifferential of $\Phi$ at $\theta$.

Expand $\partial \Phi(\theta)$ and observe that

$$
\frac{\partial \| \theta \|_1}{\partial \theta_j} = \begin{cases}
\mathrm{sign}(\theta_j), & \theta_j \neq 0 \\
[-1, 1],                 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$